# How to view closed windows in intellij?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

When I run a program in intellij I receive this output :

[image]

If I click outside this window it disappears. How can I re-view this window ?

In Eclipse I would click window -> show view -> console . Is there a similar option to view closed windows in intellij ?

Answer (score 0):

See menu View|Tool Windows|Run (IntelliJ IDEA 13). You can use option "Pin" so the toolwindow will not close automatically, see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-modes.html for more detailed explanations.